# How can I setup monitoring of Docker Container from Nagios

Tags: bash, docker, nagios

I am trying to set up a monitoring of docker container from the nagios.My nagios is on one VM and my docker is on another VM . So to monitor docker I am trying to use [the shell script below](https://gist.github.com/ekristen/11254304):

```
#!/bin/bash

# Author: Erik Kristensen
# Email: erik@erikkristensen.com
# License: MIT
# Nagios Usage: check_nrpe!check_docker_container!_container_id_
# Usage: ./check_docker_container.sh _container_id_
#
# The script checks if a container is running.
#   OK - running
#   WARNING - container is ghosted
#   CRITICAL - container is stopped
#   UNKNOWN - does not exist

CONTAINER=$1

RUNNING=$(docker inspect --format="{{ .State.Running }}" $CONTAINER 2> /dev/null)

if [ $? -eq 1 ]; then
  echo "UNKNOWN - $CONTAINER does not exist."
  exit 3
fi

if [ "$RUNNING" == "false" ]; then
  echo "CRITICAL - $CONTAINER is not running."
  exit 2
fi

GHOST=$(docker inspect --format="{{ .State.Ghost }}" $CONTAINER)

if [ "$GHOST" == "true" ]; then
  echo "WARNING - $CONTAINER has been ghosted."
  exit 1
fi

STARTED=$(docker inspect --format="{{ .State.StartedAt }}" $CONTAINER)
NETWORK=$(docker inspect --format="{{ .NetworkSettings.IPAddress }}" $CONTAINER)

echo "OK - $CONTAINER is running. IP: $NETWORK, StartedAt: $STARTED"
```

and placed the file on location /usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/ 
but in when I am run this script it tends to throw error.

**Error:**

> check_docker: line 40: syntax error: unexpected end of file

Being a java guy I really dont know much of this

So could anybody please tell how can I achieve this task of monitoring the docker as I have already wasted my time on this

Thanks for help in advance.

Answer (score 2):

**The problem is an unexpected eol char from the copy / paste.**

This is actually a Bash issue, or more specific... it's a special character at the end which you probably can't see because you probably copy/pasted from a website.

**Reason for the issue:**

Lots of sites mention eol issues, but [look here](http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~krueger/csc209h/tut/line-endings.html) for something short and to the point.

> DOS uses carriage return and line feed `("\r\n")` as a line ending, which Unix uses just line feed `("\n")`. You need to be careful about transferring files between Windows machines and Unix machines to make sure the line endings are translated properly.

**Solution:**

To fix the line endings for unix style eol, run `dos2unix file.sh` but you might need to install the utility first. In Ubuntu it would be `sudo apt-get install dos2unix`. Depending upon the environment, it could be the same for you.

**Alternatives:**

If you'd like to find out exactly what is at the end, you can look at Notepad++ on **Windows** as it understands eol chars of various formats. You need to enable all chars in the menu.

[image: Notepad++ eol setting]

On **Linux**, [Emacs Whitespace mode](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/WhiteSpace) will show the same thing:

Toggle locally with `M-x whitespace-mode RET` or see the link for (*many*) details and examples.